# Traefik 2.0: How to configure `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com`?

Tags: traefik

I just attempted to upgrade my existing pretty simple Traefik setup to 2.0.

I am using Docker as a provider.

I am running the containers with docker-compose. This is my docker-compose config:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0-alpine
    read_only: yes
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
      - type: bind
        source: ./traefik.toml
        target: /traefik.toml
      - type: bind
        source: ./acme.json
        target: /acme.json
    networks:
      - traefik
  example:
    image: example.com/example/example
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
    networks:
      - traefik
```

This is my `traefik.toml`:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[Global]
sendAnonymousUsage = true

[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
entryPoint = "https"
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
[entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "ssl@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
onDemand = false
acmeLogging = true
[acme.tlsChallenge]

[docker]
exposedByDefault = false
```

This setup works fine with Traefik 1.7.

With Traefik 2.0 I observe two issues, looking at the ACME log:

```
Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains traefik-example-deployment
Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains example-example-deployment
```

- Traefik is apparently exposing both containers. It should only expose the example container.
- Traefik is ignoring the `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com` label.

I suspect this might be due to configuration format changes in Traefik 2.0. However, although I looked through the 2.0 documentation, I was unable how the correct configuration looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routers¶

To update the configuration of the Router automatically attached to the container, add labels starting with `traefik.routers.{name-of-your-choice}.` and followed by the option you want to change. For example, to change the rule, you could add the label `traefik.http.routers.my-container.rule=Host(my-domain).`

Every Router parameter can be updated this way.
As Mentioned in Doc - https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/providers/docker/

change the `labels:` to

```
services:
  my-container:
    # ...
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.my-container.rule=Host(`my-domain`)
```

To tell Traefik not to expose Container - add - `traefik.enable=false`

As `traefik` Expose containers by default through Traefik. If set to false, containers that don't have a `traefik.enable=true` label will be ignored from the resulting routing configuration.

```
exposedByDefault (Optional, Default=true)¶
```

Comment: It turns out I was setting `exposedByDefault=false` in the wrong section, because the section is now `providers.docker` not `docker`.

Comment: I have updated the label as suggested. It is now correctly retrieving a certificate, however although https://example.com presents the correct certificate now, it returns 404.